# Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout inside RelativeLayout does not receive click events

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, onclick, android-relativelayout

I have a custom "complete box" that appears below an Android.Widget.EditText.
It's basically a **RelativeLayout with Buttons** as child views, all in a ContentView

**My hierachy looks like this** *(where RelativeLayout is Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout)*:

```
ContentView
    |-RelativeLayout
        |- EditText
        |- RelativeLayout (*)
            |- BoxView
            |- Button(s)
```

(*) The **child RelativeLayout** does **not receive** any **click gestures**.
I tried creating a custom renderer (**Android**) for the child relative layout and set it and it's children (the buttons) to  (Android.Views).Clickable = true.
I also tried setting the Z-Order and attaching the click events in the Xamarin.Forms file and also in the custom renderer

**My Custom renderer** *(ViewRenderer < Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout, Android.Views.View > )*:

```
void SetupClickableState()
{
var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(Element);

//None of the follow code makes my relative layout receive click events
renderer.View.Clickable = false;
renderer.View.ContextClickable = false;
renderer.ViewGroup.Clickable = false;
renderer.ViewGroup.ContextClickable = false;
renderer?.View?.SetZ(-999); //setting it to a positive value sets it behind my other views.

renderer.View.Click += View_Click;
renderer.ViewGroup.Click += ViewGroup_Click;

        if(renderer != null && renderer.ViewGroup != null)
        {
            var viewGroup = renderer.ViewGroup;

            viewGroup.ChildViewAdded += ViewGroup_ChildViewAdded;
            for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);

                if(child != null)
                {
                    child.SetZ(-9999);
                    child.Clickable = true;
                    child.ContextClickable = false;
                    child.Click += Child_Click;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Sadly, none if this worked so far.

Here is a screenshot, where the green is the outer layout and the blue is the inner.

[image]

**EDIT:**
I achieved that the inner rl (the blue one) now fits the whole background of the buttons, it still doesnt recognize clicks tho...

**EDIT2:**
I now found out that the area of the outer relative layout is the only place where clicks are recognized. I just made the buttons overlap the outer relative layout while they are still children of the inner relative layout, and there they became clickable. I will have to find out, how to make the area under the outer relative layout clickable...

Comment: Have you tried set `InputTransparent` to true on the external `RelativeLayout`? I wonder if this one is intercepting the event and breaking up the event propagation

Comment: I just tried it, but this makes my edittext not clickable at all, which is obviously not what I want to have

Comment: I have a feeling that your upper relative layout is overlapping your lower relative layout which is causing this problem

Comment: I doubt it, because as you can see in the screenshot: i colored the relative layouts and the green one is definitely NOT overlapping. But i found out, that only in the area of the outter layout (green one) the clickevents are recognized. I don't know how i could expand the clickable area without increasing the size of the outter relative layout.

Comment: Without complete codes, we can only guessing what you are doing wrong. Could you please provide detailed codes? or maybe a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo like github.

Comment: I honestly don't have the time to create a repo at the moment, but I'm trying to implement a TouchDelegate right now. Tested it on a dummy project and worked well.

Comment: Damn, it won't work with a touch delegate, i thought i could increase the touchable area of the outer layout, and then forward the touch to the inner, if touched under the edittext. sadly you cant exceed the bounds of a views with the touchable area. so this is no option for me.